# How to install .apk file on android device

Tags: android, apk

How can I install a `.apk` file on an android device without using the android SDK?

Comment: This should have been asked on the Android site, [where it's already been answered.](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=How+to+install+.apk+file+on+my+android+phone%3F)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Copy the `.apk` file to an SD card.
2. Download `AppInstaller` from Android Market.
3. On opening the app you can see the apk file in the list.
4. Click on the app, and it gets installed

Comment: @RahulVarma isnt there  some kind of certificate  or signing  which  can achieve  this  i  tried  downloading a  app  made  and it  didnt  open  but when i  downloaded  Z launcher  from zlauncher.com  i was  able to install it   directly  from  notification bar ..any clues  ?

Answer (score 4):

Put the .apk file up at a web site and point the phone's browser at it. You can also try emailing the .apk file to your phone. Either way, you'll have to enable installation of apps from unknown sources.

Comment: no i have sent my apk to one person how can he install in his phone

Answer (score 0):

If you are having the `.apk` file, attach that to your gmail account and send it to yourself. Then open the mail in your mobile and double click (touch) the `.apk` file. It'll be automatically installed into your android device.

If you dont' have an `.apk` file, you must download it from Android Market (Google Play) by registering with your mobile number. Choose an app from your computer (suposing you want so, otherwise just install it straight from your android device), click the install button, choose your device from the list and it will be directly installed into the device.